# Append an object and all its children

Tags: objects, parent, append

I have some objects all parented to an empty:

[image]

When I append them empty from another Blender file, only the empty is appended. All the children are missing:

[image]

How could I append the whole hierarchy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select all objects (parents + children), then it works.

Another maybe quicker solution in some cases (if you have lots of objects: join the objects to one object in the original file. Then append it and separate it again.

Maybe the "best" solution:
Move parent + child objects to a new collection. Then append the collection.